# PUT/PATCH request with not allowed fields

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, request, put

I have an application which i'm writing in Symfony 4 framework. I have a PUT/PATCH request which might contain bad request fields. For example Entities user shouldn't contain fields **description**.  In such sitaution I'd like to block request and return bad request response . I wonder what's the best way to do it  in Symfony 4?

```
In node.js implenentation such problem looks like below: 

router.patch('/tasks/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    // allowed fields
    const allowedUpdates = ['description', 'completed']
    // check if there are bad fields
    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))
    if (!isValidOperation) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' })
    }
    /*
    some response code
    /*
})
```

How can I do something similar in Symfony 4 framework?

Comment: please do not tag with irrelevant tags, hence you get downvoted by sb, this questions has nothing to do with node js so do not tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, by default when option `allow_extra_fields` is set to false (default), form with extra fields would not validate, more about this setting: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields

next you can check if `$form->getExtraData()` is an empty array, this means that there are no extra fields

if extra field were to be found to get bad request response you can either:

```
throw new BadRequestHttpException();
```

or without exception:

```
return $this->json(['error' => 'your error'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'your error', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST]);
```